# Primefaces: ImageCropper - Conversion Error Occur - croppedImage is null

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

First of all, I am using

```
Mojarra 2.0.4
Glassfish v.3.0.1
Primeface primefaces-2.2-1.jar
```

So I have a simple page that will try to crop an image, and when I try to click on a commandButton to invoke a crop action, I got this `Conversion Error Occur` when I update my `growl` message. Here is my code

```
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
<h:form>
  <table cellspacing="10">
     <tr>
         <td>
             <p:imageCropper value="#{CropImage.croppedImage}" image="#{CropImage.me.profilePic}"
                                initialCoords="225,75,500" aspectRatio="1.25" />
         </td>
         <td style="vertical-align: top;">
             <h:outputText value="My Thumb Nail" styleClass="labelText"/><br/>
             <p:graphicImage value="#{CropImage.imageName}" styleClass="icon"/><br/><br/>
             <p:commandButton value="Crop" actionListener="#{CropImage.crop}" update="msgs"/>
         </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</h:form>
```

And here is my bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="CropImage")
@ViewScoped
public class CropImage {

@ManagedProperty(value="#{SessionBean}")
private SessionBean sessionBean;

private User me;

private CroppedImage croppedImage;

private String imageName;

private String ext;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CropImage.class.getName());

public CropImage() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    me = sessionBean.getMe();
    imageName = me.getProfilePic();
    //obtain the extension
    ext = imageName.substring(imageName.lastIndexOf("."), imageName.length());
}

public String getImageName() {
    return imageName;
}

public void setImageName(String imageName) {
    this.imageName = imageName;
}

public SessionBean getSessionBean() {
    return sessionBean;
}

public void setSessionBean(SessionBean sessionBean) {
    this.sessionBean = sessionBean;
}

public User getMe() {
    return me;
}

public void setMe(User me) {
    this.me = me;
}

public CroppedImage getCroppedImage() {
    return croppedImage;
}

public void setCroppedImage(CroppedImage croppedImage) {
    this.croppedImage = croppedImage;
}

public String crop(){
    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    imageName = servletContext.getInitParameter("resources") + File.separator;
    imageName += "cropped" + File.separator + uuid.toString() + ext;        
    FileImageOutputStream imageOutput;
    try {
        imageOutput = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(imageName));
        imageOutput.write(croppedImage.getBytes(), 0, croppedImage.getBytes().length);
        imageOutput.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: So if you remove update="msgs" from your p:commandButton you don't get the error ? or is 'Conversion Error Occur' what your growl message displays ?

Comment: @Mark:`Conversion Error Occur` is what my `growl` message display

Comment: @Mark: I think my `croppedImage` is null, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Does your image to be cropped show ?

The image attribue of `<p:imageCropper>` needs to be a relative path to the image.

From PrimeFaces documentation:

> For local images, ImageCropper always
>   requires the image path to be context
>   relative. So to accomplish this simply
>   just add slash (”/path/to/image.png”)
>   and imagecropper will recognize it at
>   %WEBAPP_ROOT%/path/to/image.png.
>   Action url relative local images are
>   not supported.

Comment: Yeah I actually just figure that out as well. Lucky that they allow URL address, so I was be able to dynamically load the to be cropped image, instead of just one image. `Does your image to be cropped show ?` Funny, it does show. This is before I am using URL address, back when i had problem with `Conversion Error Occur`. Funny :D

Comment: So changing the image to a URL fixed the 'Conversion Error Occur' problem ?

Comment: yup. You can use EL to construct dynamic URL as well :D

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and came to realize it was simply the use of `File.separator` in the string used for my `ImageCropper.image` attribute. I had used it to created a path to place an uploaded image, then reused that same string.

So the problem line:

```
String uploadedPhotoPath = "uploads"  + File.separator + uploadedFile.getFileName();
```

Generated `uploads\filename.jpg`. the `p:imageCropper displayed` my images just fine, but I received the `{0} Conversion Error Occur error when trying to crop`.

I changed it to the following to resolve the issue:

```
String uploadedPhotoPath = "uploads/"+ uploadedFile.getFileName();
```

You may also find other characters such as spaces in your ImageCropper.image attribute will cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
use folder name as resources to store images and use this  code and you must use folder     name as "resources" because it will store cropped image in build and will not be able to fetch from it
index.xhtml
<h:form>
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
<h:panelGrid columns="2">  
<p:imageCropper value="#{imageCropperBean.croppedImage}" image="/resources/barca/bus.jpg"          initialCoords="225,75,300,125"/>  
<p:graphicImage id="local" value="/resources/barca/#{imageCropperBean.newImageName}.jpg"/>  
</h:panelGrid> 
<p:commandButton id="xfg" value="Crop"  action="#{imageCropperBean.crop()}" update="local" />
</h:form>
and bean code is 
package com.mangium;
import org.primefaces.model.CroppedImage;
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;  
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;  
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ImageCropperBean {

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{croppedImage}")
private CroppedImage croppedImage;  

private String newImageName;  

public CroppedImage getCroppedImage() {  
    return croppedImage;  
}  

public void setCroppedImage(CroppedImage croppedImage) {  
    this.croppedImage = croppedImage;  
}  

public String crop() {  

if(croppedImage == null)  
        return null;  


setNewImageName(getRandomImageName());  

ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContex();

String newFileName = servletContext.getRealPath("")+ File.separator + "resources" +  File.separator  + "barca" + File.separator + getNewImageName() +".jpg";

FileImageOutputStream imageOutput;  
try {  

imageOutput = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(newFileName));  

imageOutput.write(croppedImage.getBytes(), 0, croppedImage.getBytes().length); 

imageOutput.close();  
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
e.printStackTrace();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
e.printStackTrace();  
}  
return null;  
}  
private String getRandomImageName() {  
int i = (int) (Math.random() * 100000);  
return String.valueOf(i);  
}  
public String getNewImageName() {  
return newImageName;  
}  
public void setNewImageName(String newImageName) {  
this.newImageName = newImageName;  
}  
}
```